# generate N random 4digit int string & 7char string when user clicks generate button & show all when user clicks show buttonUsing sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

N keys and values are randomly generated. I tested the code which generates 4 digit string called keys and 7 character string called values based on the user input N, LB, and UB. Now I want to display keys and values using shared preference. When I run my project it only displays 1 key and value every time. Maybe I am not correctly implementing shared preferences.

This is my code for `main_activity.java`

```
package com.rough.problem.problem6;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText n,lb,ub;
    Button generate, show, quit;
    String number;
    String generatednum;
    String random_string;
    int length = 7;
    int num,min,max;
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
        lb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lowerbound);
        ub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.upperbound);

        generate= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Generate);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Show);
        quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Quit);


        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(n.getText().toString());
                min = Integer.parseInt(lb.getText().toString());
                max = Integer.parseInt(ub.getText().toString());


                for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

                    Random random = new Random();
                    generatednum = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min);

                   // Key.append(generatednum + "\n");


                    char[] chars1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
                    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    Random random1 = new Random();
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                    {
                        char c1 = chars1[random1.nextInt(chars1.length)];
                        sb1.append(c1);
                    }
                    random_string = sb1.toString();

                    //  Value.append(random_string + "\n");


                   // editor.commit();
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("key", generatednum);

                editor.putString("value",random_string);
            }
        });

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent keyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, key.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(keyIntent);
                startActivity(keyIntent);
            }
        });




    }
}
```

And the code for key.java where it should display the keys and values generated using shared preference.

```
    package com.rough.problem.problem6;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class key extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button Back;
    TextView Key, Value;
    int n,lb,ub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_key);

        Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.key);
        Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = preferences.getString("key",null);
        String value = preferences.getString("value",null);

        Key.append(key + "\n");
        Value.append(value + "\n");
    }
}
```

This is my main activity gui

[image]

and this is the Key.java activity screenshot

[image]

It only displays 1 key and value I need help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried stepping through the code? Have you tried adding breakpoints to see what the variables contain at different points in the code execution?

Comment: so far I had generated random character strings and random digits strings in key.java and output to key and value text view inside for loop. Doing this worked correctly. Now I have to save the generated values and keys and access them in another activity which is when the show button is clicked. All this should be done by shared preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only displaying one Key and Value because you're only storing one Key and Value. While your `for` loop does generate n Keys and Values, your `SharedPreferences` code is outside of the loop at the end, so only the last generated Key and Value gets stored. Since it looks like you want to store all the Keys in one `SharedPreferences` String and all the Values in another `SharedPreferences` String, this can be fixed by adding a couple variables to your Generate button's `OnClickListener`:

```
generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(n.getText().toString());
            min = Integer.parseInt(lb.getText().toString());
            max = Integer.parseInt(ub.getText().toString());

            // This will be the Key String we store in SharedPrefs
            String keyString = "";
            // This will be the Value String we store in SharedPrefs
            String valueString = "";

            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

                Random random = new Random();
                generatednum = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min);

                // Append the generated Key to the keyString
                keyString = keyString + generatednum + "\n";

                char[] chars1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                Random random1 = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    char c1 = chars1[random1.nextInt(chars1.length)];
                    sb1.append(c1);
                }
                random_string = sb1.toString();

                // Append the generated Value to the valueString
                valueString = valueString + random_string + "\n";
            }

            // Store our keyString and valueString in SharedPrefs
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("key", keyString);
            editor.putString("value", valueString);
            // Don't forget to commit your changes to SharedPrefs!
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah it makes sense. It works now.